# VBA Macros Output is displaying in a single row, So how to make it into multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my current output that my VBscript is generating.

```
ID            DESCRIPTION 1          RECURSIVE_ANALYSIS

CM-1           xxxxxxxxxxxx            Issue A
                                          Sub issue a
                                          Sub issue b
                                          Sub issue c

CM-2           yyyyyyyyyyy             Issue B
                                            Sub issue a
                                            Sub issue b
```

This is following VBA code which i have designed for getting the output

```
Sub CellSplitter1()
Dim Temp As Variant
Dim CText As String
Dim J As Integer
Dim K As Integer
Dim L As Integer
Dim iColumn As Integer
Dim lNumCols As Long
Dim lNumRows As Long
Dim wksNew As Worksheet
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim iTargetRow As Integer

iColumn = 3

Set wksSource = ActiveSheet
Set wksNew = Worksheets.Add

iTargetRow = 0
With wksSource
    lNumCols = .Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    lNumRows = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For J = 1 To lNumRows
        CText = .Cells(J, iColumn).Value
        Temp = Split(CText, Chr(10))
        For K = 0 To UBound(Temp)
            iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
            For L = 1 To lNumCols
                If L <> iColumn Then
                    wksNew.Cells(iTargetRow, L) _
                      = .Cells(J, L)
                Else
                    wksNew.Cells(iTargetRow, L) _
                      = Temp(K)
                End If
            Next L
        Next K
    Next J
End With
```

End Sub

Here is my expected output

```
ID            DESCRIPTION 1          RECURSIVE_ANALYSIS          Issues

CM-1           xxxxxxxxxxxx             Issue A                  Sub issue a
                                                                 Sub issue b
                                                                 Sub issue c


CM-2            yyyyyyyyyyy             Issue B                  Sub issue a
                                                                 Sub issue b
```

So, can someone help me to figure out to get the expected output.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Could you include some sample data or at least show us what is looks like to have a better idea of what the code is handling. I am guessing your 3rd loop logic but that is guessing.

Comment: Your sample does not illustrate why or how the data in the third column is indented for the sub issues. Can you post a screenshot with visible cell borders?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, i am adding the screenshot of my current output and also the expected output.

Comment: Here is the sample of my current output which the VBscript code is generating.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMpih.png] [1]:

Here is the sample of my expected output

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StBqx.png]

Please let me know your suggestions. @teylyn

Comment: @QHarr  : Here is the sample of my current output which the VBscript code is generating https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMpih.png]  Here is the sample of my expected output https://i.stack.imgur.com/StBqx.png] Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Please do not provide additional detail in comments. Edit your question and put the detail there. Then post a comment to notify your followers.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you didn't show the whole story, so here's a guessing:

after your code place the following

```
With wksNew' reference 'wksNew' sheet
    With .Range(.Cells(1, iColumn), .Cells(iTargetRow, iColumn)) ' reference its 'iColumn' column range from row 1 down to its last not empty one
        .Insert 'insert a new column before referenced range. now the currently referenced range is one column right shifted (i.e. its in the 4th column of referenced sheet)
        .Offset(, -1).Value = .Value ' copy values from referenced range one column to the left (i.e. in the newly created column)
        .Offset(, -1).Replace "Sub issue*", "", lookat:=xlWhole 'clear the newly created range cells containing "Sub issue..." (hence, there remains cells with "Issue .." only)
        .Replace "Issue *", "", lookat:=xlWhole 'clear the currently referenced range (i.e the one in 4th column) cells containing "Issue..." (hence, there remains cells with "Sub issue .." only)
    End With
    .Columns.AutoFit 'adjust your columns width
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Variant array is more simple.

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim wksNew As Worksheet
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vSplit, vR()

    Set wksSource = ActiveSheet
    Set wksNew = Worksheets.Add

    With wksSource
        c = .Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
        r = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        vDB = .Range("a1", .Cells(r, c))
        For i = 1 To r
            vSplit = Split(vDB(i, c), Chr(10))
            For k = 1 To UBound(vSplit)
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To c + 1, 1 To n)
                If k = 1 Then
                    For j = 1 To c - 1
                        vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
                    Next j
                    vR(c, n) = vSplit(k - 1)
                    vR(c + 1, n) = vSplit(k)
                Else
                    vR(c + 1, n) = vSplit(k)
                End If
            Next k
        Next i
    End With
    Range("a1").Resize(1, c + 1) = Array("ID", "DESCRIPTION 1", "RECURSIVE_ANALYSIS", "Issues")
    Range("a2").Resize(n, c + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is the sample of my current output which the VBscript code is generating.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMpih.png] [1]:

Here is the sample of my expected output

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StBqx.png]

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample of my current output which the VBscript code is generating.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMpih.png] [1]:

Here is the sample of my expected output

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StBqx.png]

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thank you